# parent-child linking between meshes in Babylon.js

Tags: blender, babylonjs

I have a  scene created in blender and consists of different meshes. Each mesh has child-of constraint which i have added. When this scene is exported to .babylon file and used, there is no parent-child constraint preserved. Do I add this constraint separately or is there any way to use this constraint from blender ?

If I have to add the constraint separately then how ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to let Blender export ChildOf contraints as parent relationships for Babylon directly but you can set the relationship using 'parent' on the mesh in your script. Let's say you have 4 boxes in blender A, B1, B2 and C.

A is parent of B1 and B2, 
C is child of B1.

[image]:

```
// ... after loading the scene in the browser

// store world coordinates

var wa = a.position.clone();
var wb1 = b1.position.clone();
var wb2 = b1.position.clone();
var wc =  c1.position.clone();


// set to local coordinates (storing difference vector)

b1.position = b1.position.subtract(wa);
b2.position = b2.position.subtract(wa);
c.position = c.position.subtract(wb1);


// set relationship

c.parent = b1;
b1.parent = a;
b2.parent = a;
```